Light-duty stair frame
I'm working on designing a set of wood stairs for my cats to use to get from floor height to the platform next to the windows in the basement. The platform is nearly exactly 60 inches off the ground.
My general idea is to cut 40 steps out of 2x8 (or something similar), combine them into 8 sets of five, and attach each five-set to the next at a right angle to create a sort of spiral-ish setup that makes two full "loops" to get to 60 inches above the floor. You can see an idea of a set of five in the lower right of the image.
The picture shows a general idea. The angled lines along the side of the prism are a rough idea of where the stairs would go.
I'm trying to determine the best way to frame/support the steps.
Would the whole thing be stronger with the frame inside the steps (so the steps wrap around the outside) or with the frame outside (so the stairs wrap inside)?
Would the frame be stronger if the vertical supports were at the corners, at the middle of the stairs, both, or something else?


Are the cats old or infirm? This appears to be approaching the grade of a wheelchair ramp. Forty steps at only 1.5" each seems like overkill, I have doubts a healthy cat would walk its way up and around the spiral as you expect. One or two platforms might be just as effective and much simpler.

2x8s might be overkill for cats, 1x8s or 1/2 or 3/8 plywood should be strong enough, unless you are climbing up also.  Most cat trees are more like book shelves(cat size), a pole with small platforms about every foot.

You don't need steps for a cat.  Just make ramps and cover them in carpet.

Nuclear Hoagie - Cats age and their bodies slow down same as people. I want them to be able to use the stairs and platforms when they get older. I have another set of steps that leads a different way. While they do sometimes skip the steps it is the case that they use them often as well.

crip659 - You're right that 1x8 will probably support their weight just fine. I don't think there's a big difference to the cats. I was thinking in therms of 2x8s because the actual thickness of 1.5" makes the arithmetic easy when calculating grade and number of steps. I might try to redo calculations with the 3/4" actual thickness of a 1x8 and see what I come up with.

Huesmann - I don't know what your experience with common medium-size terrestrial pets is, so I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt here and assume that you simply don't have experience thinking about quality of life for older companion animals. It's true that the cats don't NEED steps right now. That said, when they get older then they don't jump as well as they used; they need help getting up to places. It's a similar idea to humans' mobility issues that come with age. So consider this planning for the future as well as the present.
